# Returning a boolean function

Tags: c++, boolean

I wish to make to make the contains Element function return either true or false, but it's not returning anything at all. Any help is appreciated heavily!

```
bool Set::containsElement(int x) const
{
    int element = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < _numItems; i++) {
        if (_items[i] == x)
            element = true;
    }
    return element;
}

// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "Set.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Set s1, s2, s3;

    s1.addElement(7);
    s1.addElement(3);
    s1.addElement(5);

    s1.containsElement(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's an indent at "return element".

Comment: What makes you think it's not returning anything?

Comment: It didn't show in the debugger console screen or as a value in the output.

Comment: But you don't store or use the result of the function anywhere?

Comment: You are not returning a boolean function, you are returning a boolean from a function.  Return values in C++, if you do not put them somewhere just go away.  To print, print it.  To store, store it somewhere (sah=y `bool b = s1.containsElement(3);`).  You need to read a beginning C++ primer.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I've resolved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

When you call the function in main, you are calling it to no where, so the value is simply lost when called

Comment: I actually have tried calling the function with  std::cout << &Set::containsElement;

Comment: But it just kept returning 1 :/

Comment: `1` means true! Try `std::cout << Set::containsElement(3);`

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns the value properly. You just fail to use it in your `main()` function. You need to do something more like

```
if(s1.containselement(3)))
{
   // Do whatever you want now that you know it's contained
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First af all element should be declared as 'bool' not 'int'

```
std::cout<< s1.containsElement(3)<<std::endl;
```

will show true or false